# How select only all first child of another div

Tags: html, css

Suppose to have this html code:

```
<div class="colora_riga">
     <!--only this div-->
     <div>
         <div>...</div>
     </div>
     <!--only this div-->
     <div>
        <div>...</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want take the all only first child directly of div with colora_riga like class. I dont' want the div another div. This is my css:

```
.colora_riga > div:first-child {
    border:1px ridge #999999;  
}
```

This rule works only for the first child of div with "colora-riga" like class, for the second directly child the rule is not applied. Anyone can help me?

Comment: By using the immediate child selector `>`, like this `.colora_riga > div {...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want every div directly under `.colora_riga`, you don't need `:first-child` then :

```
.colora_riga > div {
    border:1px ridge #999999;  
}
```